# Axis fault: "Service class must have public as access Modifier"

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis

I am trying to build a simple Web Service. I follow [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) and it works just fine.

But when I change to creating interface for the `Converter` class, Eclipse auto included both `IConverter.class` and `Converter.class` but when I run test, it always return this result:

```
<soapenv:Reason>
    <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
        Service class wtp.IConverter must have public as access Modifier
    </soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

I have public keyword in the code of iConverter and its methods.

Here is my java source:

Interface:

```
package wtp;
public interface IConverter {
    public float celToF(float cel);
    public float fToCel(float f);
}
```

Implementation:

```
package wtp;

public class Converter implements IConverter {

    @Override
    public float celToF(float cel) {
        return cel * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }

    @Override
    public float fToCel(float f) {
        return (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
}
```

services.xml:

```
<service name="IConverter">
    <Description>
        Test ws
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">wtp.IConverter
    </parameter>
</service>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>TestWS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your wtp.iConverter class declared as a public class?

Comment: @bithead61 I added my code, classes are my implement, and the xml files are auto gen by eclipse

Comment: @jtahlborn I added, please help

Comment: It's weird the error message is a lower-case `i`; did you change the name of something?

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ sorry, that was mistake from copy, it's Service class wtp.IConverter must have public as access Modifier

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the interface name as your service class -- pass the name of the class that implements the interface.  Axis2 is trying to create an instance of your service class using reflection.  The parameter definition in services.xml should be as follows:

```
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false"> wtp.Converter </parameter>
```

Comment: You are correct, I was facing the same issue and your post helped me.  thanks. Can you figure out the reason it was created services.xml file with service class as an Interface name instead of its Impl class name which was a problem.